# Selecting multiple nodes using xpath in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I an trying to get data using XPath.

I can reach the data what I want, but when there are multiple data, only the first one is selected. 
And I want to count the number of target data.

For example, I want to count the numbers of queues whose message-vpn's name is vpn/b.
XML structure is as follows:

```
<queues>
    <queue>
        <name> queue/a </name>
        <info>
            <message-vpn> vpn/a </message-vpn>
        </info>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name> queue/b </name>
        <info>
            <message-vpn> vpn/b </message-vpn>
        </info>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name> queue/c </name>
        <info>
            <message-vpn> vpn/b </message-vpn>
        </info>
    </queue>
</queues>
```

And here's the xpath script I used.

```
/queues/queue/info/message-vpn[text()=("vpn/b")]
```

When I access the data, only queue/b is selected, not c.
Please help me to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original xpath expression fails because the text `vpn/b` is surrounded by spaces. So another way to do it is

```
/queues/queue/info/message-vpn[normalize-space()=("vpn/b")]
```

If you want to count the number of these queues, use the `count()` method:

```
count(/queues/queue/info/message-vpn[normalize-space()=("vpn/b")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
//queues/queue/info/message-vpn[contains(.,'vpn/b')]
```